# Find max(hour_count) for a time period

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following format:

```
+----+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| id | cur_date   | cur_hour | hour_count | cumu_count |
+----+------------+----------+------------+------------+
| 56 | 2016-01-01 | 00:00:00 |          8 |          8 |
| 57 | 2016-01-01 | 01:00:00 |          6 |         14 |
| 58 | 2016-01-01 | 02:00:00 |          3 |         17 |
| 59 | 2016-01-01 | 03:00:00 |          1 |         18 |
| 60 | 2016-01-01 | 04:00:00 |          6 |         24 |
| 61 | 2016-01-01 | 05:00:00 |          7 |         31 |
| 62 | 2016-01-01 | 06:00:00 |         29 |         60 |
| 63 | 2016-01-01 | 07:00:00 |         35 |         95 |
| 64 | 2016-01-01 | 08:00:00 |         49 |        144 |
| 65 | 2016-01-01 | 09:00:00 |         63 |        207 |
| 66 | 2016-01-01 | 10:00:00 |         64 |        271 |
| 67 | 2016-01-01 | 11:00:00 |         62 |        333 |
| 68 | 2016-01-01 | 12:00:00 |         57 |        390 |
| 69 | 2016-01-01 | 13:00:00 |         58 |        448 |
| 70 | 2016-01-01 | 14:00:00 |         48 |        496 |
| 71 | 2016-01-01 | 15:00:00 |         36 |        532 |
| 72 | 2016-01-01 | 16:00:00 |         22 |        554 |
| 73 | 2016-01-01 | 17:00:00 |         18 |        572 |
| 74 | 2016-01-01 | 18:00:00 |         16 |        588 |
| 75 | 2016-01-01 | 19:00:00 |         10 |        598 |
| 76 | 2016-01-01 | 20:00:00 |          7 |        605 |
| 77 | 2016-01-01 | 21:00:00 |          4 |        609 |
| 78 | 2016-01-01 | 22:00:00 |          2 |        611 |
| 79 | 2016-01-01 | 23:00:00 |          1 |        612 |
+----+------------+----------+------------+------------+
```

What I want to do is go through each day (I provide a month), and it returns me the day, hour and hour_count that has the most fields. In this case, 10:00:00 has the hour with the highest count, so it should return

```
+-----------|------------|------------+
|cur_date   |  cur_hour  |  hour_count|
+-----------+------------+------------+
|2016-01-01 | 10:00:00   | 65         |
|2016-01-02 | ?          | ?          |
```

I'm using the following query but it isn't returning accurate results:

```
mysql> select cur_date,cur_hour, max(hour_count) from hour_data where cur_date like '2016%' group by cur_date;
+------------+----------+-----------------+
| cur_date   | cur_hour | max(hour_count) |
+------------+----------+-----------------+
| 2016-01-01 | 00:00:00 |              64 |
| 2016-01-02 | 04:00:00 |              67 |
| 2016-01-03 | 04:00:00 |              43 |
| 2016-01-04 | 05:00:00 |             640 |
| 2016-01-05 | 00:00:00 |             672 |
| 2016-01-06 | 00:00:00 |             675 |
| 2016-01-07 | 00:00:00 |             705 |
| 2016-01-08 | 00:00:00 |             696 |
| 2016-01-09 | 00:00:00 |             203 |
| 2016-01-10 | 00:00:00 |              89 |
| 2016-01-11 | 01:00:00 |             673 |
| 2016-01-12 | 00:00:00 |             708 |
| 2016-01-13 | 00:00:00 |             710 |
| 2016-01-14 | 00:00:00 |             731 |
| 2016-01-15 | 00:00:00 |             675 |
| 2016-01-16 | 00:00:00 |             222 |
| 2016-01-17 | 00:00:00 |             112 |
| 2016-01-18 | 00:00:00 |             683 |
| 2016-01-19 | 00:00:00 |             709 |
| 2016-01-20 | 00:00:00 |             690 |
| 2016-01-21 | 00:00:00 |             696 |
| 2016-01-22 | 00:00:00 |             643 |
| 2016-01-23 | 00:00:00 |             282 |
| 2016-01-24 | 00:00:00 |             189 |
| 2016-01-25 | 01:00:00 |             757 |
| 2016-01-26 | 00:00:00 |             765 |
| 2016-01-27 | 00:00:00 |             770 |
| 2016-01-28 | 00:00:00 |             805 |
| 2016-01-29 | 00:00:00 |             786 |
| 2016-01-30 | 00:00:00 |             394 |
| 2016-01-31 | 00:00:00 |             146 |
| 2016-02-01 | 00:00:00 |             797 |
+------------+----------+-----------------+
32 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

The date and the max(hour_count) is correct, but the cur_hour is not the correct hour.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: I don't have that option.

Comment: Any assistance here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to take a scripting approach to solve the problem.